# Boost VS2017 linking to the wrong DLL

Tags: visual-studio, boost, cmake

I have a CMake file which does this:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem)

add_library(MyModule MODULE main.cpp)
target_include_directories(MyModule PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(MyModule Boost::system Boost::filesystem)
```

I'm using VS 2017 as my generator.  When I generate the project file with `cmake`, it finds `boost_system-vc141-mt-1_63.lib` and I can see that it is in the linking rules of the vcxproj. However, when I try to compile I get this error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_system-vc140-mt-1_63.lib

Note the different generators (vc140 vs vc141).  I know my compiler has output the right values because I built boost from source, so I tried to just rename vc141 to vc140, but the error stayed the same.  I also confirmed that vc140 is not referenced in the project file.

What's going on?  How can I force boost to link to the correct version?

Comment: Added my solution below.  Posted this so I could find it later when I run into the same problem.  When I found the solution it's because a colleague mentioned "Auto link".  I wouldn't have found the solution otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building with Visual Studio, boost has some `pragma` statements which do the linking for you.  This is called "Auto-linking" and it over-rides any command-line arguments you may be passing to the linker.

The solution is to define `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`.  This can be done in two ways:

1. In source code before including boost headers as `#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`.
2. It could be added to your cmake file as: `add_definitions("-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB")`.
3. As of CMake 3.5: Use the `disable_autolinking` imported target:

   `target_link_libraries(MyModule Boost::system Boost::filesystem Boost::disable_autolinking)`

Comment: Just a hint: I don't think the 2nd solution will work. That only defines a CMake cached variable named `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`. If I look at the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) it would say one solution is to add `Boost::disable_autolinking` dependency like `target_link_libraries(MyModule Boost::system Boost::filesystem Boost::disable_autolinking)`

Comment: @Florian, both solutions in the answer solved this issue for me, but so did your suggestion. Upvotes all around. :)

Comment: It has been a few months since I wrote this.  Since then, I've learned about Florian's `Boost::disable_autolinking` which was introduced in cmake 3.5 and can confirm that it is the real way to go.